# Send ArrayList<String> from BaseAdapter to Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I am trying to send an ArrayList via intent.putExtra to my Activity. In my Activity i then only see that the position (int) arrived succesfully, but the ArrayList(s) is/are null.

```
  ArrayList<String> resultTitle, resultText; 

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View rowView;
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_adapter_listview_layout, null);

                if (resultTitle.get(position) != null) {
                    resultTitleTV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
                    resultTitleTV.setText(resultTitle.get(position));

                }
                if (resultText.get(position) != null) {

                    resultTextTV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
                    resultTextTV.setText(br2nl(resultText.get(position)).substring(0, 50) + "....");

                }

                rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TheNews.class);
                        intent.putExtra("position", position);
                        intent.putExtra("Title", resultTitle);
                        intent.putExtra("Text", resultText);
                        context.startActivity(intent);

                        Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + resultTitle.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                return rowView;
            }
```

This is how my Activity gets the BundleData:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int position;
           if (extras != null) {
            position = extras.getInt("position");
            newsTitle = extras.getStringArrayList("Title");
            newsText = extras.getStringArrayList("Text");

            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "You have clicked position Number: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (newsText.get(position) != null) {

                text = br2nl(newsText.get(position));    
                toolbarTheNews.setTitle(newsTitle.get(position));
                descriptionTV.setText(text);
            }
        }
```

**Now it works**

Okay thanks to all, now it works. I just changed the ArrayList in the Activity into static.

```
static ArrayList<String> newsText;
static ArrayList<String> newsTitle;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int position;
    if (extras != null) {
        position = extras.getInt("position");
        newsTitle = extras.getStringArrayList("Title");
        newsText = extras.getStringArrayList("Text");

        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "You have clicked position Number: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (newsText.get(position) != null) {

            text = br2nl(newsText.get(position));
            toolbarTheNews.setTitle(newsTitle.get(position));
            descriptionTV.setText(text);
        }
    }
```

In the BaseAdapter i send the Values like following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, TheNews.class);
intent.putExtra("position", position);
intent.putExtra("Title", resultTitle);
intent.putExtra("Text", resultText);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

I didn´t change the putExtra into putStringArrayListExtra and still works. But what is the difference between both of them?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the data from the `Bundle` using `getStringArrayList()` then you need to put the extra into the `Intent` using `putStringArrayListExtra()`.

Answer (score 1):

**u want to store  StringArrayList then Use**

**putStringArrayListExtra**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,activityName);
 intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", value)

 context.startActivity(intent);
```

**and**

**second activity u get the value with**

**getStringArrayListExtra**

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  intent.getStringArrayListExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pass ArrayList** from **BaseAdapter** to **Activity** using **Intent**:

```
ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Put ArrayList** in **Intent** in **BaseAdapter**

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(MyCurrentActivity.this, MyNextActivity.class);
i1.putStringArrayListExtra("list_key", mList);
mContext.startActivity(i1);
```

**Retreive ArrayList** from **Intent** in **Activity**

```
ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();


Intent i2 = getIntent();
mList = i2.getStringArrayListExtra("list_key");

for (String string : mList) {
    Log.i("Element", string);
}
```

**Done**